# Problems accessing JSON data from API in React/Redux with Thunk

Tags: object, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm working with the NHL API in a React/Redux project. I am using Thunk and Axios to make an API call in the action like so:

```
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchRangersStats() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_RANGERS_STATS"})
        axios.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/3/stats')
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_RANGERS_STATS_FULFILLED",
                    payload: response.data.stats[0].splits[0]
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_RANGERS_STATS_REJECTED",
                    payload: err
                })
            })
    }
}
```

I am able to retrieve the API data and have it set up in my App.js like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.scss';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { fetchRangersStats } from './actions/fetchRangersStats-action';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.fetchRangersStats();
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.props.rangersStats.data.stat);
    const stats = this.props.rangersStats.data;

    console.log('Type : ' + typeof(this.props.rangersStats.data.stat));

    return (
      <div className="App">

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchRangersStats: () => dispatch(fetchRangersStats())
})

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  rangersStats: state.fetchRangersStatsReducer
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

This works and I can retrieve the API data just fine but I am having an issue accessing nested object properties and their values. `this.props.rangersStats.data` gives me this:

[image]

If I go one level deeper into the `stat` object I get via `this.props.rangersStats.data.stat` it works and I get this:

[image]

That works just fine, but when I try to grab data from within the `stat` object using something like `this.props.rangersStats.data.stat.gamesPlayed` or any other property within `stat` I get an undefined error.

Why can't I used dot notation to grab the properties and their values with `stat`? i.e. gamesPlayed, wins, losses, etc..

What is the proper way to access the data within `this.props.rangersStats.data.stat`? I'm new to Redux and Thunk so bear with me.

Here is the reducer :

```
export default function reducer (state = {
    data: [],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null
}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "FETCH_RANGERS_STATS": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: true
            }
        }
        case "FETCH_RANGERS_STATS_REJECTED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                error: action.payload
            }
        }
        case "FETCH_RANGERS_STATS_FULFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                fetched: true,
                data: action.payload
            }
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: share your reducer code, also add the error

Comment: I added the reducer. The error I keep getting when trying to access anything within `stat` is an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that data inside your state is defined as an array

```
state = {
    data: [],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null
}
```

but you are assigning to the array an object {} (action payload is an object)

```
data: action.payload
```

This can explains the error you're getting when trying to grab deeper with dot notation the properties and their values

Comment: I tried switching data to an object or even an empty string but I still get the same undefined error when trying to go deeper into `stat`.  How could I fix this?

Comment: in reducer try to  data: ...action.payload    (object clone) and share the code in codepen so we can debug it